# I want to render a few frames and all I get is a black screen

Tags: rendering

To escape Blender I tried to export the particle simulation to fbx by baking the animations and then bring it in and then I can render it very easily there.

I was unable to bake the animation of flocking birds, so I'm forced to render in Blender but I still cannot figure out how to render frames.

Can anyone just show me even by pictures where to click to render one frame the correct camera

Comment: I just found out that to render you hit F12 but where is the actual button?!

Comment: It's on the left side of the top tool bar under _Render_ (next to File, Edit, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

The 'active camera' is the one used for rendering. To make a camera the active camera, click on it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad 0</kbd>.

To render a single frame you press  <kbd>F12</kbd> or in the top left corner click *Render > Render Image*.

[image: Render Image]